# Upload da imagem para dentro do contexto do projeto java jsf

Tags: primefaces, java-ee, upload, jsf-2.2

Tenho um projeto em `JSF` de pedido de venda.
Umas das partes é adicionar a imagem ao produto, fazendo o `upload` da imagem.
Para isso estou usando o componente do `primefaces p:fileUpload`, ele funciona, mas a imagem é "jogada" para a pasta do PC e não para a pasta do projeto, preciso que esta imagem vá para a pasta dentro do projeto, em `WebContent-Images`.

**Método de upload:**

```
public void upload(FileUploadEvent event) {
        UploadedFile uploadedFile = event.getFile();
        try {
            File file = new File("", uploadedFile.getFileName());
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            out.write(uploadedFile.getContents());
            out.close();
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,
                    new FacesMessage("Upload completo", "O arquivo " + uploadedFile.getFileName() + " foi salvo!"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,
                    new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "Erro", e.getMessage()));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia,

Não acho que seja uma boa copiar para a pasta do projeto, uma vez que toda hora que você for atualizar o projeto você irá perder as imagens que já foram carregadas.

Talvez seja melhor você colocar em uma pasta específica e na hora de ler a imager olhar para esta mesma pasta

Para alterar o caminho da leitura é só você passar na hora de criar o File assim

```
public void upload(FileUploadEvent event) {
        UploadedFile uploadedFile = event.getFile();
        try {
            File file = new File("/tmp/pasta_imagens/", uploadedFile.getFileName());
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            out.write(uploadedFile.getContents());
            out.close();
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,
                    new FacesMessage("Upload completo", "O arquivo " + uploadedFile.getFileName() + " foi salvo!"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,
                    new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "Erro", e.getMessage()));
        }
    }
```

Comment: blz,obrigado pela atenção.